# Unable to download a byte range from S3 object using AWS Go SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to download a particular data chunk from S3. Following is the code snippet.

```
func DownloadFromS3() ([]byte, error) {
 retries := 5
 awsSession = session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
    SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    Config: aws.Config{
        MaxRetries: &retries,
        LogLevel: aws.LogLevel(aws.LogDebugWithHTTPBody),
    },
    }))

    // Create S3 service client
    serviceS3 = s3.New(awsSession)
    d := s3manager.NewDownloaderWithClient(serviceS3,func(d *s3manager.Downloader) {
        d.Concurrency = 10 // should be ignored
        d.PartSize = 1     // should be ignored
    })
    w := &aws.WriteAtBuffer{}
    n, err := d.Download(w, &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("mybucket"),
        Key:    aws.String("key1"),
        Range:  aws.String("bytes=0-9"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return w.Bytes(), err
}
```

But this keeps downloading part by part continuously till the entire object is retrieved; without downloading only the specified part. Am I missing any configurations here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with the Go SDK; try the s3.GetObject instead of downloader.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it was an issue with the SDK they have fixed it in the v1.8.33

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with previous AWS-Go-SDK. It's now fixed https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/pull/1311